# How can I have multiple Swiper slideshows on a single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper Slideshow](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.VdXau_TA8mE). I'm using [this particular version](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/02-responsive.html). Here's [the exact code](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/02-responsive.html) I'm using.

When adding a second Swiper, the pagination doesn't work properly.

I tried giving a different class to the second Swiper container but it didn't work.

How can I have two of this in the same page?

Thanks.

Comment: The broken code link here is exactly why code needs to be in questions.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Their support sent me this [**DEMO**](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/demos/320-multiple-swipers.html). It works!

You don't need to do anything to the JS File.
All you need to do is add an extra class to pagination, add an extra class to the slideshow, and differentiate the rest of the classes on everything else (see code below). With this, you can have as many slideshows as you want on the same page.

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container swiper1">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination1"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container swiper2">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination2"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="../dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
  var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination1',
      paginationClickable: true,
  });
  var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper2', {
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination2',
      paginationClickable: true,
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 17):

I had a case where I needed 3 identical sliders on the same page and I didn't want to duplicate any code, nor did I want to hardcode anything. This is how I solved it

```
// Function that actually builds the swiper 
const buildSwiperSlider = sliderElm => {
    const sliderIdentifier = sliderElm.dataset.id;
    return new Swiper(`#${sliderElm.id}`, {
        navigation: {
            nextEl: `.swiper-button-next-${sliderIdentifier}`,
            prevEl: `.swiper-button-prev-${sliderIdentifier}`
        },
        pagination: {
            el: `.swiper-pagination-${sliderIdentifier}`,
            type: 'progressbar',
        },
    });
}

// Get all of the swipers on the page
const allSliders = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper');

// Loop over all of the fetched sliders and apply Swiper on each one.
allSliders.forEach(slider => buildSwiperSlider(slider));
```

As you can see from the above code the key here is assigning an identifier to each of the sliders. In my case, I opted to use a `data-id` property and reference that. Like this

```
<div class="swiper" data-id="ID_OF_FIRST_SLIDER">
...
</div>
<div class="swiper" data-id="ID_OF_SECOND_SLIDER">
...
</div>
<div class="swiper" data-id="ID_OF_THIRD_SLIDER">
...
</div>
```

And pagination/navigation element just incorporate the identifier as part of their class name.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is passing here in search for a solution to conflicts with prev and next button between multiple swipers, this is what fixed it for me (Nuxt.js/SSR project):

1) Add id attributes to button's divs:
`<div id="button-next-relacionados" class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>`
`<div id="button-next-relacionados" class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>`

2) In the swiper options object, refer to the new ids instead of `swiper-button-prev` and `swiper-button-next` classes:

```js
swiperOption: {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 6,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '#button-next-relacionados',
          prevEl: '#button-prev-relacionados'
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

My current Swiper version is 3.4.2. When I click on the next-prev button, all the sliders on the page moves.

For set different next-prev buttons I done this:

```
<div class="swiper-pager">
  <div class="swiper-button-next></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev></div>
</div>
```

=>

```
<div class="swiper-pager">
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-next_slideshow<?=$module?>"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev_slideshow<?=$module?>"></div>
</div>
```

And in js:

```
$('#slideshow<?=$module?>').swiper({
  mode: 'horizontal',
  slidesPerView: 1,
  pagination: '.slideshow<?=$module?>',
  paginationClickable: true,
  // nextButton: '.swiper-button-next', // not work properly
  // prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev', // not work properly
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next_slideshow<?=$module?>',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev_slideshow<?=$module?>',
  spaceBetween: 30,
  autoplay: 2500,
  autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,
  loop: true
});
```

Comment: Hi this works perfectly fine when we click on either arrows or bullets and all stays in sync. Just a question if it is possible with touch swipe as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i=1;
var str1='sliderBox_'
var str2='.sliderBox_';
$('.swiper-container').each(function (index,value) {

    var classAdd = str1 + i;
    var classCall = str2 + i;
    var next_slider = 'slider-next' + i;
    var prev_slider = 'slider-prev' + i;
    $(this).addClass(classAdd);
    $(this).parent().siblings(".sites-slider__prev").addClass(prev_slider);
    $(this).parent().siblings(".sites-slider__next").addClass(next_slider);
    new Swiper(classCall,{
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 20,
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ('.' + next_slider),
            prevEl: ('.' + prev_slider),
        },
        breakpoints: {
            1199: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
            },
            991: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
            },
            600: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
            },
        }
    });
    i++;



});
```

Comment: effective solution because it avoids repeating the code unnecessarily if the sliders are identical.

Answer (score 2):

@David Martins
Thanks a lot, but in current version 4.5.0, you need to modify a little js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Init Swiper
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination1',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  // Enable debugger
  debugger: true,
});
var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper2', {
  autoHeight: true,
  pagination:  {
    el: '.swiper-pagination2',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  // Enable debugger
  debugger: true,
});
```

anyway, thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 2):

1. add another class like:

   ```
   class="swiper-container two" ...
   ```
2. append the class in js like:

   ```
   new Swiper('.swiper-container.two', { ...
   ```

This is how it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice easy **Vanilla Javascript** way of doing it

just change the 'large-slider' class to whatever you're using as your slider name, same with the prevs and next classes for the arrows.

full example here on codepen

https://codepen.io/davenoham/pen/YzQWdge

```
const largeSlider = ()=>{
  let largeSliders = document.querySelectorAll('.large-swiper')
  let prevArrow = document.querySelectorAll('.prev')
  let nextArrow = document.querySelectorAll('.next')
  largeSliders.forEach((slider, index)=>{
    let sliderLength = slider.children[0].children.length
    let result = (sliderLength > 1) ? true : false
    const swiper = new Swiper(slider, {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: result,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: nextArrow[index],
            prevEl: prevArrow[index],
        },
        speed: 1000,
    }); 
  })
}
window.addEventListener('load', largeSlider)
```

Comment: hey hey! Awesome solution, you code wrap here in stack is a little off, but your codepen was perfect! 

... And to add to @Mr.No excellent solution here is if you need pagination too:

```let pag = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-pagination");
...
more code
...
pagination: {
  el: pag[index],
  type: "bullets",
  clickable: true,
},```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution for it. You can just create navigation dynamically  by enabling `{createElements: true}`. It will generate navigation dynamically you also need to enable navigation to add navigation into dom. Otherwise nothing will happen.

```html
new Swiper('.color-carousel', {
    slidesPerView: 8,
    spaceBetween: 8,
    loop: true,
    modules: [Navigation],
    navigation: true,
    createElements: true,
  });
```

here is the official docs https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-createElements

Answer (score 1):

I checked all the answers here, but they have unnecessary code.
First parameter of `new Swiper()` constructor can be dom element and so we can implement it like below. In this approach, we can avoid duplicate code and don't need to use any extra ids nor classes.

HTML

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
const sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-container');
for (let slide of sliders) {
    const nextEl = slide.getElementsByClassName('swiper-button-next')[0]
    const prevEl = slide.getElementsByClassName('swiper-button-prev')[0]
    let carousel = new Swiper(slide, {
        navigation: {
            nextEl,
            prevEl,
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If both *.swiper* elements use the same settings (for example, if you are using *.swiper* blocks in a content builder CMS like WordPress Gutenberg), you can also do it like this:

```
// Select all elements with the class 'swiper'
const swiperElements = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper');

// Loop through each '.swiper' element and initialize Swiper
swiperElements.forEach(swiperElement => {
  const swiper = new Swiper(swiperElement, {
    lazy: true,
    speed: 300,

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: swiperElement.querySelector(".swiper-button-next"),
      prevEl: swiperElement.querySelector(".swiper-button-prev"),
    },
  });
});
```

This approach doesn't require adding different classes, and the navigations automatically work separately.

Answer (score 0):

You were going down the right path - you need to add a different class to the second swiper but you **also** need to add references to the new class in `dist/js/swiper.min.js` otherwise it will only be targeting elements using the original class. It should just be a case of copying the relevant sections and repeating them with the new ID (same as what I had to do with wow.js).

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I believe I found the answer. I got it to work without touching swiper.min.js

Comment: Excellent news! Glad you got it sorted without the fiddling :) adding it to the .js file is done in the same way you added it to the inline js, same thing but in a different place pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with using multiple auto-initialized instances while using Framework7 Core to update slide results based on the data values.

The missing piece for this use case was assigning an `id` to the swiper container, for example:

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper-init" id="swiper-instance-{{
userId}}">
```

This little bit of magic causes everything to work again, otherwise it tries to re-use the Swiper instances and gets very confused about which one the instance belongs to. Once again Vladimir has thought of everything :)

Answer (score 0):

(Example in CodePen: https://codepen.io/rasaf-ibrahim/pen/mdrVQEq )

We need to add extra classes on HTML and change classes on CSS and JS to make multiple swiper slideshow work in a single page.

***Step-1:***
Let’s first take a look at the HTML files of the swiper slideshow

```
<!— HTML of swiper-1 -->

   <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?car)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?tree)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?tiger)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?water)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?dog)"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper - Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

<!—HTML of swiper-2 -->

<div class="swiper-container ">
   <div class="parallax-bg" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?space)" data-swiper-parallax="-23%"></div>
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
      <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus
          felis iaculis nec. Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300" data-swiper-parallax-opacity="0">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
      <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus
          felis iaculis nec. Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
      <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus
          felis iaculis nec. Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo. Integer laoreet
         </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
  <!-- Add Navigation -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
</div>
```

***Step -2:***
Let’s first Identify classes that are common in the CSS file of both swiper slideshow.

```
/* CSS of swiper-1 */

   
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;

    }

/* CSS of swiper-2 */

.swiper-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  
width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.swiper-slide {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px 60px;
}

.parallax-bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 130%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}

.swiper-slide .title {
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.swiper-slide .subtitle {
  font-size: 21px;
}

.swiper-slide .text {
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.3;

}
```

As we can see,
**.swiper-container** and **.swiper-slide** are common classes

***Step -3:***
Now, let’s identify classes that are common in the JS file of both swiper slideshow.

```
// JS File of Swiper-1

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container ', {
    effect: 'coverflow',
    grabCursor: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    coverflowEffect: {
      rotate: 50,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 100,
      modifier: 1,
      slideShadows: true,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
  });

// JS file of swiper-2

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 600,
    parallax: true,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  });
```

As we can see,
**.swiper-container** and **.swiper-pagination** are common classes

***Step-4:***
Now let’s add extra classes on the common classes **(.swiper-container .swiper-slide .swiper-pagination)** of the HTML file

```
<!— HTML of swiper-1 -->

  <div class="swiper-container swiper-container1">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide1" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?car)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide1" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?tree)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide1" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?tiger)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide1" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?water)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide1" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?dog)"></div>
      </div>

    <!-- Swiper - Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination1"></div>
  </div>


    <!—HTML of swiper-2 -->

<div class="swiper-container swiper-container2">
  <div class="parallax-bg" style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/800x600/?space)" data-swiper-parallax="-23%"></div>
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide  swiper-slide2">
      <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
      <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus
          felis iaculis nec. Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide2">
      <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300" data-swiper-parallax-opacity="0">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
      <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus
          felis iaculis nec. Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide2">
      <div class="title" data-swiper-parallax="-300">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="subtitle" data-swiper-parallax="-200">Subtitle</div>
      <div class="text" data-swiper-parallax="-100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus
          felis iaculis nec. Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination2 swiper-pagination-white"></div>
  <!-- Add Navigation -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
</div>
```

**Step-5:**
Now let’s change those common classes with the newly added classes on both CSS and JS.

**CSS:**

```
/*  CSS of swiper-1 */

   
    .swiper-container1{
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .swiper-slide1 {
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;

    }
  
/* CSS of swiper-2 */

.swiper-container2{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #000;
}

.swiper-slide2 {
font-size: 18px;
color: white;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 40px 60px;
}

.parallax-bg {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 130%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;

}

.swiper-slide .title {
font-size: 41px;
font-weight: 300;
}

.swiper-slide .subtitle {
font-size: 21px;
}

.swiper-slide .text {
font-size: 14px;
max-width: 400px;
line-height: 1.3;

}
```

**JS:**

```
//  JS of swiper-1

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container1', {
    effect: 'coverflow',
    grabCursor: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    coverflowEffect: {
      rotate: 50,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 100,
      modifier: 1,
      slideShadows: true,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination1',
    },
  });


  // JS of swiper-2 

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container2', {
  speed: 600,
  parallax: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination2',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me using in nuxtjs with multiple swipers on page

used id instead of class in options

```
   <div
      :id="`swiper-button-prev-${element}`"
      class="swiper-button-prev"
    ></div>
    <div
      :id="`swiper-button-next-${element}`"
      class="swiper-button-next"
    ></div>
```

...
Options:

```
navigation: {
  nextEl: `#swiper-button-next-${this.element}`,
  prevEl: `#swiper-button-prev-${this.element}`,
},
```

to get unique id, I used

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

example of generated output:
element: 47bfe557-d75f-455c-9a37-85b7935b297b

package.json

```
"dependencies": {    
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
 },
```

on child component, might not be the best way but seem to work

...

```
<ComponentName v-if="element" />
```

...

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

...

```
data() {
  return {
    element: null,
  }
}
```

...

```
mounted() {
  this.element = uuidv4();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to increment the button classes.

Make sure they are **already present in the DOM** and that they are **children of the parent element** declared in the "new Swiper() function". They will work in the context of their parent only.

Simply specify your swiper for each use in a page.

Personally, I prefer to target my swipers by unique ids. Something like this:

```
<div class="swiper-container" id="swiper-top">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <button class="swiper-button-prev"></button>
    <button class="swiper-button-next"></button>
</div>
```

Then use this unique id as an initializer :

```
var swiper = new Swiper("#swiper-top", {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 12,
    grabCursor: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
    navigation: {
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    }
});
```

Note that my buttons are initialized in the function, although they are already present in the DOM. So you don't need to give them a different class each time.

Hope you find it useful !

Answer (score 0):

you can use select querySelectorAll

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container myswiper">
   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
</div>
<!-- Add Pagination -->
<div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination1"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container myswiper">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
</div>
<!-- Add Pagination -->
```

```
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="../dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
 var myswiper;
 var allMySwipers = document.querySelectorAll('.myswiper');

  allMySwipers.forEach(sw => {
        myswiper= new Swiper(sw, {
                                pagination: '.swiper-pagination1',
                                paginationClickable: true,
                                });
  });
 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to be able to dynamically differentiate for a n number of slider per page(for example, developing widgets which you can place an unlimited number of times on a page), I like to add a GUID/UUID at the end of each class that controls the slider. This ensures all slider instances will behave as expected. You can also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-do-i-create-a-guid-uuid) on how to create GUID/UUIDs in JS:

For example:

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container swiper-GUID/UUID">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-GUID/UUID"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container swiper-secondGUID/UUID">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-secondGUID/UUID"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="../dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
  var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper-GUID/UUID', {
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination-GUID/UUID',
      paginationClickable: true,
  });
  var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-secondGUID/UUID', {
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination-secondGUID/UUID',
      paginationClickable: true,
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).